# How to efficiently update a timer to firestore?

Tags: firebase, time, google-cloud-firestore, countdowntimer

I have a timer in an android app, it's time left should be displayed in another app or website.

Now to achieve this I could simply update the time every second, but of course this method would be very costly. Therefore I want to find another way of coding this kind of task.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is your current setup? You could just record the start time and the end time and handle the countdown client side.

Comment: How would I make sure that the time is the same in different timezones? And how could I handle pauses? Thanks